# Show that the metric $d_1$ on $C([0,1])$ does not give rise to a complete metric space.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Show that the metric $d_1$ on $C([0,1])$ does not give rise to a complete metric space.

$$
d_1(f,g) = \int_0^1 |f(s)−g(s)| \, ds
$$

Comment: Think about the metric. What do you think the completion of the space will be? Consider the functions $f_{n}(x) = x^n$ and $g(x) = 0 \forall x \in [0, 1)$ and $g(1) = 1$. Why might this work? See @RonMor's response on how you might fill in the details.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please let us know what work you've done towards and answer and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far?

My recommendation:

1. find a Cauchy's series $f_n$ that you think "should" converge to some function $f$, but $f \not\in C([0,1])$.
2. Define $K=C([0,1])\cup${$f$}
3. show that $d_1$ is still a metric, and $\lim f_n = f$
4. Conclude by the uniqueness of the limit, there is no limit for $f_n$ in $C([0,1])$, hence it is not complete.

If you won't be able to find such series I'll try to help you with that.

Best of luck

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely the structure I need to follow for my solution. 

I have already been trying to find a series like that but I'm just struggling with where to start finding an example. 

Thanks for the help!